# [PHP]How to use foreach to add AND or OR statement into a sql query?

Tags: php, sql, oracle, foreach

Hi guys I am trying to perform multiple criteria search in my PHP, so I wanted to use foreach to add AND statement automatically based on the number of user selection. Below is my code:

```
$sub = trim(ucfirst($_POST['sub']));
$any = trim(ucfirst($_POST['key']));
$count = 0;
$query = "SELECT P.PTY_ID, P.PTY_UNITNUM, P.PTY_STREET, P.PTY_POSTCODE, P.PTY_SUBURB,P.PTY_CITY, T.P_TYPE_NAME, 
                  L.SALE_PRICE, L.AVAILABILITY, R.PTY_ID,F.FEAT_ID, R.FEAT_ID,F.FEAT_NAME   
          FROM PROPERTY_TYPE T, PROPERTY P, LISTINGS L, PROPERTY_FEATURE R, FEATURE F 
          WHERE P.P_TYPE_ID = T.P_TYPE_ID(+) 
          AND P.PTY_ID = L.PTY_ID(+)
          AND R.FEAT_ID= F.FEAT_ID
          AND R.PTY_ID= P.PTY_ID
          AND REGEXP_LIKE (P.PTY_SUBURB,'$sub')
          AND REGEXP_LIKE (P.PTY_STREET||P.PTY_POSTCODE,'$any')
          OR(
                ".foreach ($_POST["check"] as $feat_id) {
                    if ($count != 0)
                        echo "AND";
                    echo "FEAT_ID = ' . $feat_id . '";
                    $count++;
                }.")";

$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($stmt);
```

So in my case, I want to search properties by suburb, some keywords like postcode and street name, as well as features. In order to respond to the users' selection on multiple features, I tried to use the foreach loop to print "AND FEAT_ID = (posted id)", but I got a syntax error after the "OR" part till the end of the query, saying that some expression is expected. 
I am quite new in PHP study at the moment. Can someone point out the correct format for me?  Cheers(:

Comment: You should learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax and *never* use the deprecated `(+)` syntax for outer joins.

Comment: OK, cheers@GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure 100% what your issue is, but i would clean it up a little. Again this is my coding style so others may still think this can be improved.

```
$sub = trim(ucfirst($_POST['sub']));
$any = trim(ucfirst($_POST['key']));
$count = 0;
$or = "";

if (isset($_POST["check"]))
{
    $featArray = [];
    foreach ($_POST["check"] as $feat_id)
    {
        array_push($featArray, "FEAT_ID = " .$feat_id);
    }

    $or = implode(' AND ', $featArray);
}

$query = "SELECT P.PTY_ID, P.PTY_UNITNUM, P.PTY_STREET, P.PTY_POSTCODE, P.PTY_SUBURB,P.PTY_CITY, T.P_TYPE_NAME, 
                  L.SALE_PRICE, L.AVAILABILITY, R.PTY_ID,F.FEAT_ID, R.FEAT_ID,F.FEAT_NAME   
          FROM PROPERTY_TYPE T, PROPERTY P, LISTINGS L, PROPERTY_FEATURE R, FEATURE F 
          WHERE P.P_TYPE_ID = T.P_TYPE_ID(+) 
          AND P.PTY_ID = L.PTY_ID(+)
          AND R.FEAT_ID= F.FEAT_ID
          AND R.PTY_ID= P.PTY_ID
          AND REGEXP_LIKE (P.PTY_SUBURB, '$sub')
          AND REGEXP_LIKE (P.PTY_STREET||P.PTY_POSTCODE, '$any')";

if ($or != null)
    $query .= " OR (" . $or . ")";

$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $query);
oci_execute($stmt);
```

I'd also check that your $_POST['sub'] and $_POST['key'] or set.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lots(:

Answer (score 0):

@Lee Stevens
Thanks for the idea! The use of .= you mentioned solve my problem perfectly.
To fit my use i have modified the codes into this:

```
<?php
    $sub = trim(ucfirst($_POST['sub']));
    $any = trim(ucfirst($_POST['key']));
    $count = 0;
    $and = "";  
/* All the same above */

    if (isset($_POST["check"]))
    {
        $featArray = [];
        foreach ($_POST["check"] as $feat_id)
        {
            array_push($featArray, "AND F.FEAT_ID = " .$feat_id);
            /* Add an "AND" here coz the original codes can't print */
            /* the "AND" for some reasons */
        }

        $and = implode(" ", $featArray);
        /* Remove "AND" here */
    }
    $query = "SELECT P.PTY_ID, P.PTY_UNITNUM, P.PTY_STREET, P.PTY_POSTCODE, P.PTY_SUBURB,P.PTY_CITY, T.P_TYPE_NAME, 
                      L.SALE_PRICE, L.AVAILABILITY, R.PTY_ID,F.FEAT_ID, R.FEAT_ID,F.FEAT_NAME   
              FROM PROPERTY_TYPE T, PROPERTY P, LISTINGS L, PROPERTY_FEATURE R, FEATURE F 
              WHERE P.P_TYPE_ID = T.P_TYPE_ID(+) 
              AND P.PTY_ID = L.PTY_ID(+)
              AND R.FEAT_ID= F.FEAT_ID
              AND R.PTY_ID= P.PTY_ID
              AND REGEXP_LIKE (P.PTY_SUBURB,'$sub')
              AND REGEXP_LIKE (P.PTY_STREET||P.PTY_POSTCODE,'$any')";


    if (!empty($and))
        $query.="$and";

    $stmt = oci_parse($conn, $query);
    oci_execute($stmt);
?>
```